# HTML5 email input pattern validation to not allow personal email addresses

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation

What's a regular expression that could be used for [input pattern validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#pattern_validation) so that email addresses that include `@gmail.com`, `@hey.com`, or `@fastmail.com` are not treated as valid?

```
<input
  type="email"
  required
  pattern="..."
  title="Please provide your work email address">
```

Comment: There's nothing inherit to the string of a domainname that lets you build a pattern to filter out addresses based on how people use their email address.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: You can't tell by the domainname whether an email address is used as a personal account

Comment: you could  match those three domains with something like `/\@gmail\.com$|\@hey\.com$|\@fastmail\.com$/` -- but short of an exhaustive list of all valid domains and their usage, it's not possible to "not allow personal email addresses" with a regex.

Comment: There are plenty of small businesses that use an `@gmail.com` email address for non-personal use; filtering these domains will be unlikely to accomplish what you think it should.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this negative lookahead (`?!...`) to exclude the specified domains.

Here is the fixed code:

```
<input
  type="email"
  required
  pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?!gmail\.com|hey\.com|fastmail\.com)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
  title="Please provide your work email address">
```